# MySQL: Selecting min and max values from different rows depending two different ENUM values

Tags: mysql, enums, dependencies, max, min

Well, this title may be perplexing, so let me try to explain my problem by showing some tables and queries. I have a table '_commision' that contains the following rows amongst others:

```
+-------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
| id    | relation_id | type | min_commission | max_commission | percental |
+-------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
| 22892 |        3427 | SALE |           1.40 |           1.80 | yes       |
| 22891 |        3427 | SALE |          30.00 |          60.00 | no        |
| 21075 |        6365 | LEAD |          30.00 |           NULL | no        |
| 19638 |        4436 | SALE |           1.10 |           NULL | yes       |
| 19637 |        4436 | LEAD |          30.00 |           NULL | no        |
+-------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to get the absolute min_commission value and the absolute max_commission value. The tricky part is the percental column, as you will see later. My first idea was to go like this:

```
SELECT rc.type, rc.currency_id, rc.percental, 
    MIN( rc.min_commission ) AS min_commission, 
    IF( MAX(GREATEST( rc.min_commission, rc.max_commission )) > MIN( rc.min_commission ) , MAX(GREATEST( rc.min_commission, rc.max_commission )) , 0.00 ) AS max_commission
FROM _commission rc
LEFT JOIN ...
GROUP BY rc.type;
```

This query results the following rows:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| type | currency_id | percental | min_commission | max_commission |
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| LEAD |           1 | no        |          30.00 |           0.00 |
| SALE |           1 | no        |           1.10 |          60.00 |
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I need to get a result, that considers the column 'percental' because if the type is 'SALE', the commission can be 1.4% and $30 for example as well (percental or fix). As you can see, I need a result like the following, but I cannot get a suitable query. This is how the result should look like:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| type | currency_id | percental | min_commission | max_commission |
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| LEAD |           1 | no        |          30.00 |           0.00 |
| SALE |           1 | yes       |           1.10 |           1.80 |
| SALE |           1 | no        |          30.00 |          60.00 |
+------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    SELECT 
            rc.type, rc.currency_id, rc.percental, 
            MIN( rc.min_commission ) AS min_commission, 
            IF( MAX(GREATEST( rc.min_commission, rc.max_commission )) 
            > 
            MIN( rc.min_commission ) , MAX(GREATEST( rc.min_commission, rc.max_commission )) , 0.00 ) AS max_commission
    FROM 
            _commission rc
    LEFT JOIN ...
    GROUP BY 
            rc.type, rc.percental;
```

Comment: Ufff.... hahaha! Shame on me :D I couldn't see the wood for the trees. Need sleep - or coffee. Thanks Hytool! hahaha....